# User delta query confusion

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the `deltaLink` retrieved from a request to the `users/delta` endpoint on the v1.0 Microsoft graph API, do subsequent requests (using the `deltaLink`) returned from each previous request return changes since the **initial** request, or from the last request?

I am confused as to what the intended scenario is for the endpoint.  Is the token a long-lived thing, that you use in your application for a while to keep reusing to track changes from some initial sync, or is it a temporary method to see changes between two points in time, and then the token is discarded?

Right now it appears to "accumulate" changes since the token was created, which I guess makes sense, but if left to live for a long time would requests would potentially accumulate a lot of changes.

Comment: I just skipped through this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview. Your last statement is incorrect, it's like a bookmark of where you're up to. If left for a long time, subsequent changes would accumulate, yes, but there will always be less data requests required than if you had to query from the start again (unless there are more changes than actual data)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Your description of a bookmark is a much better wording for what I was trying to describe by "accumulate".  If you had an application running for say, months you would want to periodically discard the delta token and just get a new one if the number of changes became a problem.  It seemed strange to me because you need to parse the delta response for changes if you are reusing it.

Comment: Whether you do a delta reload or a full reload comes under 'performance optimisation'. Sometimes it's quicker to always just do a full reload. It's almost always simpler. When there is a _lot_ of existing data and you need it up to date quickly, you use deltas. PS I meant to say "correct" in my comment - I'm just so used to saying "incorrect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a `deltaLink`, it returns everything that has changed since that `deltaLink` token was issued. The results will also include a *new* `deltaLink` token that you use for your *next* poll of the system.

In other words, it is similar to the source code control systems like Git work. When you execute `git pull`, it looks at last commit in your local repository and then pulls down all of the changes that have occurred since that commit. In this example, Git's commit id is the delta token.

For example, you can start syncing Users "from now" using this query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta
```

The results will look something like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$deltatoken=4Pqov5cPSZPKjBZh-vGbekLcJ2oUTc1kzqA0XhF-lJrEmf3B2i-HyS72r9jBIqHuZUzdMopk5VyHnAI6_qh59FjavhOmaTmQW4JPL2bLKu5LpQ3m_zMSsp6M3Os03KOgaeay0zwAa08QefM1ArkZzkB_pUmZyV6MIS1eN7JHnBOgotBPFyPb-dnjAcheWE9W0HkUR87kf3jsuA4Ja4QTRnN3Hj_4eYdzoYxLWi54Aq2bHWTbDlPtl76M8Bhw8jiq37Y4R-G7G0eZNuRt43CBY0l3XliXXR5Ubi4ZUGApDAGVSPNc_VdHV4H3nbaB5qvwZZ7tAfqZB0-06-ZI-a0y2hxAPJLnI-iTB2PXdqxnaZn4f26k0khW52C57czh9KOjfE3nYV6pwEDFRFu-qj4062eMQwo2H6yoCLysv-C-XIOK3nDTaR3BPDOPGqNbnZkmB33-MXe9gcCPojAoU9ql95Z9de5QPnqezWVfBhXj_sRv3RlQQfCkGJHg3ZTVkdA475xJuHOhy2po38KlT3FmN0rzg0jOjvfPyTGrRI24C58ushGouckqHcCQllr4Dby9ECsPjVcNFEklSddjllaRMOkpUilecEdHnxsy0zH60bKkc2-6fcUvYuya8y4-7IySvbpk241ldxvoO9EQpDnUCdh3GgxKnYNuLtOiqiGdYVgGgTJa-iBQ1xVghcpsEMD9NqrByB3mSmy9rRKN3WP_C_HQBnEpV7Z3dvu-8ZxewMEhEObhhv8H_15msP4Bm6KvfuO-0EyNaMy_OXvGKpdkczSVQsdZ4jDmsAw_itqqtZmNoa3URjxjt0KAYNo9IrBXBx9yUGt6K_sY1xybfLxwBYOGOaV7zNd7XFaVXL8OM1hG2JGF0H4dM33uppuX5pWrrU0NBDcf9nbNkJf53fec-R1aX9BmEaAtv2xblxL75Kl0j8JKay2iBM7JaebqbGaZV6es9HUVFCIB6mxcNVDmR55U2Tel_D1TZ44eOwoZtvZvLPdQvQKuDYnwM1Yt9JJWXiGKigKi515UBPI52jhSnL1cY8VFnVDz4b81WgaRESSPipzC7fixQ94lvSaQ1MqJXRoWcm3LnjBMb7Z_aF4H_OFJNrGW-v8O__ZozNHUq04-v7rScKu3Cu64bISp1Z18DUeuRn9_Nc3vhXwhi2YlXxsX0mn-iKYjlGgE8MFSkcChpbtFLN3Wejublt3wlZ4yHQhySLDxFkgiA95BZLEXhdyVbfTzdW9cCUf9beltUT8qgcoLGH4lGdo2qjZqmUOZ8vfbPYCiExmOkN0qazvkGUs-VOcl37sccB2VEgqWodzy_Haq9HJJgAhFt_GeuL9VG58cPZPfKi0Q6DImdBE3p7NC36VvpgTbmz7G8N2V_BV8HC7e1lTiaLBkxXMEgcn_Uzl2gqPqc3CJxd3gTm7Z6MxgQXFZynwTXxo1CXSoSuLhMaND79EBrLOa11vd8aYmDwl5xuAXJZ7hZ0fVAuYe9JEUE2BvJYgBUijNi7ug8-_E73kcRQL5K2KbdTtUZRqFDxEnOBpC1adc1Pn633gC18z6Itzy5j6IXlutTBdlrAM-urzcxHX364VhnXwtWhLSEhB0xnBj-PejvfdzyuC3hTW6cLI-CttpgH-oMNDcrweeCB8NGOJYyxwFsYDZ9X3fwDYEhIwhUwdJOqG_10KJYVaRLUvdhgTkaEQdeRrJc2fyyDXAhJ7aIkr0PNy0ue1yn346cypSZw8BRAx6i3d4BTKgCxwnOqK8x6iMOb1Ad2IomKHoxH1_PkPIgMEz1mDcfipvG1IImuMj333wNe8tbPuPBsmQq-t-4GF4mH3sQkvt3pMdcnb4ITqLaZ5xR5Hxbyig6bENFyMR_5w_Q3LugXIIRknWB21jxWbcMOY1ggaYZno-MBFA2ueFDox8ImN4A9orD-8XpgbSqywqv5dnh4rCDoate27oMkz8NEGW6UdZUOSBrC0k91FKO2yHUa8KDA3tTKMIgDU-ynS0hOzfc_4cUICDpQJJOv2tXsWigkuVshJc-1733CXF3ptA8llB9dFPt6_-oWKAjxvHRq6_X8mX2Siz9D2kTXpfUS-AKmEpKcphNWzpIg5K8iKMy-xB_insLCYbkjFkxU5Q6-VnjS6KRolOXaRSejh2faVxFbgIFrOP6Ns5inBJZUemAPV7TTxY_RIGh3f4nMbzxU2P5doyYP7wTr_aiLDw1uJrDxjXRLPzLseS1uizlLpZMPw-QIAUARFyUzj7k4U9bzXoX_9URA5acvETVZOebdUbR3kCOOoBMmbdELX7uUkICPu_T0fsbGLAKA4wZSIIYdqCUydMQk9NofgvE28v-NB2g4-fFPuFANn0H4b0ktFrBT8wUO61ElrnwsL1tLyx6kP4s1y6OaH_ARTpb9StCkcvbO2bh4HYLj09xnxgbx_4RPUI6cag6mjCRhNTIipj3feZ0pBEVlL7NiTavSV2Ho2gGJujurYSE4cdF-Gjtraeulj0ur1buEwVQX8LbLWbO76X4cQLhE7G2Yf7GV8tjW2DX4TdG9yRciPaBntE0Imxe6IKZnSEEyqXMsZIRWLBfI3WIiVka-QD9lJlPZAdkNMb5VqQxyqruiCZ3nK-R7njc1EoVDejJEDOGyAljhF_kvcxsd_Hu0G8QHi0JtXXm8Tm9hH1O7EtEIDQAHR0tt6ihHixK2IYdfmoe3EIHJ_VmlC37RqTHf2ru2FgkoutuNLII9tYsMhWEEin-tgFwdCvUA0ONHytNY2I0EFKkx56t9JGoupL-lwpnhtnqpnVAPAgAk93D01fBz2NSNlXs_z3E8SOmXud35RNCG62i_nmzHICz_WRwKMHEbqelSst9U2h5FY.uzRUQfIEYUBmAFBUnNWTJn2yfL9toRZ2_VNuoRrA7jg",
    "value": []
}
```

The value of `@odata.delaLink` is a URI that points to the state of `Users` as of the specific moment in time the URI was generated. If nothing has changed and you follow `@odata.delaLink`, you will receive an empty data set and a *new* URI. If you then add a new User, calling the `deltaLink` would return only that new user.

Comment: Sounds like what I expected `/delta` to do, but if I keep following the delta link, I always get back all changes that have happened since the very first call without a token.

Comment: Every time you poll the endpoint you will get a new token (`deltaLink`). It sounds like you are continuing to use the original token.

Comment: Brilliant - it was a bug.  I was only updating my `deltaLink` after following the `nextLink`s... So single pages did not update the link and it began a loop.  Should've guessed!  Since it does behave as you said, this endpoint is awesome...